# Bootstrap Carousel Image Doesn't Align Center Horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code :

```
<style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 510px;
    max-width: none;
  }
</style>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div style="background-color: red;" class="slider col-lg-10">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="first-slide img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/underconstruction.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
        </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- item active -->
      <div class="item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="assets/img/underconstruction.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
        </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="assets/img/underconstruction.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
        </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- item -->
    </div><!-- carousel-inner -->
  </div><!-- slider col-lg-10 -->

  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" style="background-color: blue;" class="tabs-vertical col-lg-2 visible-lg">TAB 1</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" style="background-color: yellow;" class="tabs-vertical col-lg-2 visible-lg">TAB 2</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" style="background-color: cyan;" class="tabs-vertical col-lg-2 visible-lg">TAB 3</div>

  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" style="background-color: blue;" class="tabs-horizontal col-xs-4 hidden-lg">TAB 1</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" style="background-color: yellow;" class="tabs-horizontal col-xs-4 hidden-lg">TAB 2</div>
  <div data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" style="background-color: cyan;" class="tabs-horizontal col-xs-4 hidden-lg">TAB 3</div>
</div><!-- carousel slide -->
```

I managed to get this on wide screen :
[image]

and this on narrow screen :
[image]

if you take a look closely the image in the narrow screen is not aligned properly in center, it is placed on the left. I want to make it to center.

And also I can't make the image to fill all the spaces there's still some red section which means it doesn't filled up.

Please help, I spend hours of research and still come with nothing.

I see some margin solution but it doesn't help.

I've tried to set the width, it is centered but it doesn't fill top and bottom of the carousel. And also it become small in narrow screen.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to do using the image through an image tag since then you need the element to center, keep aspect ratio and overflow in special cases. Instead, I would suggest you use the image as `background-image` on some other than `img` element and then use `background-position: 50%` and `background size: auto 100%` or so to achieve the desired effect. I would also suggest you try to reformat your question into something usable by others, this example only helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the image as css `background-image` of a `div` instead of using the `img` tag. Then set `background-size: cover;`:

```
div {
  background-image: url(path/to/img/relative/to/css);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}
```

Drawback of this method is that you need to specify the div width and height, but any image you use will fill it then so it should be a problem.

Here's an example:
http://jsbin.com/jayacopoga/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: `background-size: cover` is unable to provide this outcome, `contain` might, but with an additional media query for the smaller state.

Comment: Cover fills the container preserving aspect ratio. You should only add `background-position: 50%` to center the image. I'll add that to the answer. Or maybe I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Well, maybe it was me then who didn't. Glad OP has it working.

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap Carousel image centering**, works in Bootstrap 3 and 4-alpha. 
All that is needed is to add the style `text-align:center;` to the carousel item div's that you desire to center. The others will align to the left.

This centers the image and does not change its size. If you need it to fill up the entire carousel panel with the image, just change the image width to 100% and it will fill and be centered as a result (see third image in code below).

This is the carousel example directly from Bootstrap 4 alpha. The extra styling is all that is needed to center the image (adding the 'center' class to the carousel-item div in this case) and can be achieved using various methods.

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

```
<style> .center { text-align:center; } </style>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active center">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/tech" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img style="width:100%;" src="http://placeimg.com/200/200/people" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```